# ngSwitch in Angular 5 to display the text or textarea

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ngSwitch to display either the text or text area based on the format type id.

For every question, I want to display text area or an input text. But for every FormatType Id, it is displaying textarea though the FormatType does not match the value 3121.

```
<mat-card>
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let question of Questions">
    <div class="col-6">
      <p>{{question.Question}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" [ngSwitch]="question.FormatType.Id">          
      <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="3121">            
        <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]="question.Answer" name="questionField" maxlength="1000" 
        [required]="RequiredFields" [disabled]="true"></textarea>
        
      </mat-form-field>
      
      <mat-form-field *ngSwitchDefault>
        <input type="text" matInput [required]="RequiredFields" autocomplete="off" 
        [(ngModel)]="question.Answer" name="questionField" maxlength="1000"/>
      </mat-form-field> 
            
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

Initialization has helped, but both the text and text area are always disabled. I just want textarea to be disabled but if it's a text it should be enabled. I tried `[disabled]="false"` for text, but then everything is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling there might be 2 errors in your code :

First, an `*` requires you to put a variable name. So, the "variable 3121" is probably undefined. You need to update your template like the following :

```
<div class="col-6" [ngSwitch]="question.FormatType.Id">          
  <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'3121'">            
    <textarea ... ></textarea>

  </mat-form-field>
      ...
  <mat-form-field *ngSwitchDefault>

  </mat-form-field> 

</div>
```

Secondly, there might be an issue with your `question.FormatType.Id` where `Id` might be undefined as well.

Comment: Initialization has helped, but both the text and text area are always disabled. I just want textarea to be disabled but if it's a text it should be enabled. I tried [disabled]="false"for text, but then everything is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this solution

i have create demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-delete-record-fnkbw6?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

> ts file code

```
Questions = [
    {
      Question: 'Question 1',
      Answer: 'Answer 1',
      FormatType: {
        Id: '3121655'
      }
    },
    {
      Question: 'Question 2',
      Answer: 'Answer 2',
      FormatType: {
        Id: '3121'
      }
    },
    {
      Question: 'Question 3',
      Answer: 'Answer 3',
      FormatType: {
        Id: '3121'
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML syntax for the Material input fields valid, however, for this type of problem the data source needs to be tested before it gets to the HTML template, so it is recommended first create a JSON structure with sample question data in your typescript code like this:

```
Questions: any[] = 
[
    { FormatType: { Id: 3121 }, Question: "Question 1", Answer: "Answer 1" },
    { FormatType: { Id: 3122 }, Question: "Question 2", Answer: "Answer 2" },
    { FormatType: { Id: 3123 }, Question: "Question 3", Answer: "Answer 3" }
];
```

Then in the ngInit() (or after the question data has been initialized or loaded) add a console log to filter the data for the field value that you want to match and display the result:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Number of questions of format type 3121 = ' + 
        this.Questions.filter(q => q.FormatType['Id'] === 3121).length);
}
```

This output then tells you how many records will be matched with the switch filter or if there is a problem with the structure or data within the question data array.